After downloading template and applying it to Laravel project animations with WOW.js doesn't work
I bought a template for my laravel project and everything works like tailwind and etc. Only thing that doesn't work is animations that use WOW library. When running NPM RUN BUILD this is the error:
PS C:\Users\Netas\Herd\encodium11> npm run build
> build
> vite build

vite v5.4.0 building for production...
transforming (14) node_modules\fizzy-ui-utils\utils.js
../images/NoisePattern.svg referenced in ../images/NoisePattern.svg didn't resolve at build time, it will remain unchanged to be resolved at runtime
✓ 88 modules transformed.
x Build failed in 2.08s
error during build:
resources/js/index.js (8:7): "default" is not exported by "node_modules/wowjs/dist/wow.js", imported by "resources/js/index.js".
file: C:/Users/Netas/Herd/encodium11/resources/js/index.js:8:7

 6: import { tns } from 'tiny-slider';
 7: import Isotope from 'isotope-layout';
 8: import WOW from 'wowjs';
           ^
 9:
10: window.wow = new WOW.WOW({

    at getRollupError (file:///C:/Users/Netas/Herd/encodium11/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:392:41)
    at error (file:///C:/Users/Netas/Herd/encodium11/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:388:42)
    at Module.error (file:///C:/Users/Netas/Herd/encodium11/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13958:16)
    at Module.traceVariable (file:///C:/Users/Netas/Herd/encodium11/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:14406:29)
    at ModuleScope.findVariable (file:///C:/Users/Netas/Herd/encodium11/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:12110:39)
    at MemberExpression.bind (file:///C:/Users/Netas/Herd/encodium11/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:8834:49)
    at NewExpression.bind (file:///C:/Users/Netas/Herd/encodium11/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:4808:23)
    at AssignmentExpression.bind (file:///C:/Users/Netas/Herd/encodium11/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:4808:23)
    at ExpressionStatement.bind (file:///C:/Users/Netas/Herd/encodium11/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:4808:23)
    at Program.bind (file:///C:/Users/Netas/Herd/encodium11/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:4804:28)


This is index.js
import '../../node_modules/tiny-slider/dist/tiny-slider.css';
import '../css/animate.css';
import '../css/style.css';

import '../js/typewriter';
import { tns } from 'tiny-slider';
import Isotope from 'isotope-layout';
import WOW from 'wowjs';

window.wow = new WOW.WOW({
  live: false,
});

window.wow.init({
  offset: 50,
});


I tried everything and I am already second day debugging this I just can't find solution anymore.
Reinstalling wow.js
Tried to change import type
If i change class from WOW to animated
<h1 class="animated fadeInUp"> testing</h1>
like this then it works
